# How to print grouped boxplots onto a pdf document and label the outliers

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a data frame similar to the one created with this code:

```r
Location <- rep(c("FL", "GA", "SC", "NC"), each = 5)
ID <- data.frame(ID=(c(12,122,242,329,595,130,145,245,654,878,863,425,24,92,75,3,200,300,40,500)))
set.seed(1)
Copper <- sample(1:100,20,replace=T)
Iron <- sample(1:100,20,replace=T)
Carbon <- sample(1:100,20,replace=T)
Lead <- sample(1:100,20,replace=T)
Mg <- sample(1:100,20,replace=T)
CaCO <- sample(1:100,20,replace=T)
Zinc <- sample(1:100,20,replace=T)
data <- cbind(Location,State,ID,Copper,Iron,Carbon,Lead,Mg,CaCO,Zinc)
```

Note: I don't know how to create a mock data set that contains a few extreme outliers, which would be useful for this question, if someone wants to include that in an answer it would be awesome.

I can create boxplots for each variable (`Copper`:`Zinc`) grouped by `Location` like this:

```r
#example shown for Copper
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data, aes(x=Location, y=Copper, color = Location))+
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle("Copper") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I have been doing this same process for each variable(`Copper`:`Zinc`). I would like to know a faster way to accomplish this -without having to copy and paste so much- and print the plots onto a pdf document. Do I have to use pivot_longer() first? I would also like to know how to label only the outliers in each plot using ggplot2?

Comment: What is `Location` in your dataframe ? You forget to provide it in your example

Comment: @dc37 apologies `State` was supposed to be `Location`, I fixed it

Comment: That's what I thought, I answer using `State` instead of `Location`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using `facet_wrap` to get several panels on a single plot**

Without to replicate your code for each Elements, you can have the use of `facet_wrap` function in `ggplot2` to have all boxplot on a single page (that you can after save in the way you like). (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html)

To do that, you need first to reshape your data in order to place all elements in a single column and all values in a second columns, you can achieve this by using the `pivot_longer` function from `tidyr`:

```r
library(tidyr)
data %>% pivot_longer(.,-c(State,ID), names_to = "Element", values_to = "Value") 

# A tibble: 140 x 4
   State    ID Element Value
   <fct> <dbl> <chr>   <int>
 1 FL       12 Copper     68
 2 FL       12 Iron       89
 3 FL       12 Carbon     44
 4 FL       12 Lead       81
 5 FL       12 Mg         73
 6 FL       12 CaCO       24
 7 FL       12 Zinc       28
 8 FL      122 Copper     39
 9 FL      122 Iron       37
10 FL      122 Carbon     25
# … with 130 more rows
```

Now, you can get your plot as you did before except, you indicate to `ggplot2` to create a single panel for each Element by using `facet_wrap(~Element)`:

```r
data %>% pivot_longer(.,-c(State,ID), names_to = "Element", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = State, y = Value, color = State))+
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(.~Element)
```

[image]

**Labeling outliers with their ID**

To label outliers with their ID, you can first create a new column to identify them. here, I'm using `dplyr` to create a new column (after pivoting the dataframe) to determine if each point is an outlier:

```r
DATA <- data %>% pivot_longer(.,-c(State,ID), names_to = "Element", values_to = "Value") %>%
  group_by(State, Element) %>%
  mutate(Outlier = ifelse(Value > quantile(Value,0.75)+1.5*IQR(Value) | Value < quantile(Value,0.25)-1.5*IQR(Value), "Out","in"))

# A tibble: 140 x 5
# Groups:   State, Element [28]
   State    ID Element Value Outlier
   <fct> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>  
 1 FL       12 Copper     68 in     
 2 FL       12 Iron       37 in     
 3 FL       12 Carbon     70 in     
 4 FL       12 Lead       87 in     
 5 FL       12 Mg         45 in     
 6 FL       12 CaCO       59 in     
 7 FL       12 Zinc       43 in     
 8 FL      122 Copper     39 in     
 9 FL      122 Iron       89 in     
10 FL      122 Carbon     40 in     
# … with 130 more rows
```

Now, we can use `geom_text` (or `geom_text_repel` from `ggrepel` package) to label this outlier by subsetting the dataframe to keep only points marked as Outlier and use `label = ID` as argument in the `aes` in order to display the ID of each of this outliers:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(DATA, aes(x = State, y = Value, color = State))+
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text_repel(data = subset(DATA, Outlier == "Out"), aes(label = ID))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(.~Element, scales = "free")
```

[image]

**To loop over plot to get only one single plot per page**

If you are looking to plot only one element per page and loop over all elements, starting from `DATA` (with outliers identified), you can loop over each value of "Element" by creating a `for` loop:

```r
element <- unique(DATA$Element) 
for(i in 1:length(element))
{
  g <- ggplot(subset(DATA, Element == element[i]), aes(x = State, y = Value, color = State))+
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_text_repel(data = subset(DATA, Element == element[i] & Outlier == "Out"), aes(label = ID))+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3, hjust = 1)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_blank())  +
    ggtitle(element[i]) + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
  ggsave(g,filename = paste("test",element[i],".png"), width = 5, height =5, units = "in" )
}
```

here, I saved it as `png`, but you could do the same for pdf or any other format.

Comment: i should have been more specific in my post. When I said I want to label the outliers, I meant I wanted the ID number of the outlier to appear where the dot is on the graph (or above/below the graph)(I will fix for the reference of future readers). Also for reference, what would I change if I wanted one graph per page?

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. Hope it is what you are looking for.